# .Net tools for decompiling

Tags: c#, .net, il, decompiler

Are there API tools within the core .Net framework (any version) which help in decompiling code?

Note: I am not looking for an external tool (such as reflector or dotPeek), I am coming from the direction of trying to build an external tool.

Comment: There's [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx), but as the name implies it does not generate high-level source code.

Comment: On hold? I am looking for pointers to standard .Net libraries

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a decompiler with public source code, I believe [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) is what you are looking for.

ILSpy is an open source decompiler and you can download the entire Solution from the project's [GitHub](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy).

Comment: Very interesting....I'll look into this and get back to you

Comment: I provided the links to the projects homepage and source, and stated what the project was and completely answered the question, even according to the user who asked it. The relevance of the question to SO is irrelevant with regards to my answer, so I am curious why someone would downvote this answer. Maybe they don't like ILSpy ;)